# Android studio showing error Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

even after installing Build tool version each time.It will shows same error

```
Error:Failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.3
<a href="install.build.tools">Install Build Tools 23.0.3 and sync project</a>
```

And again While creating new project in android studio each time SDK are getting downloaded.

Comment: In gradle, change your `Build tool version` to the version that you used in previous project.

Comment: Use `android {
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
}`

Comment: Thanks Check did the same but same problem

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.restaurant_app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti : When I try to create new project in android studio. Every time SDK are getting downloaded. And When I got error 
"Install Build Tools 23.0.3 and sync project" After installing It will again give me same error.